# Can eyeglasses slowly "burn" one's eyes similar to using a magnifier glass?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, geometric-optics

can eyeglasses (either concave lenses as in near-sight glasses or convex lenses as in far-sight glasses) burn your eyes (maybe even very slowly over the years) the same way a magnifier glass would burn a paper under sunlight? Also can any damage be caused from an indoor light source such as 100W incandescent bulb?

*Clarification: The question asks about normal indoors and outdoors usage of eyeglasses and not about direct (and dangerous) staring at the light source.*

Comment: In fact one of the health advantage of eyeglasses is that many reduce the exposure of your corneas to UV light, thus protecting your sight and prolonging the time until you get cataracts. This is also a reason for people with good sight to employ UV blocking sunglasses or outdoor activities.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but no more than the eyes of a person with good vision and no glasses.

The eye has a lens like a magnifying glass or eyeglasses. The purpose is to focus light on your retina. This is just like focusing light from the sun onto paper. If you look into the sun, your eyes will be damaged. The only reason your retina doesn't burn is your eyes are smaller than a magnifying glass. They don't gather as much sunlight.

Paper doesn't burn unless you focus sunlight to a point. If you hold the magnifying glass too close or too far from the paper, it is focused to a circle. The paper gets warm, but not hot enough to burn.

In your eye, lenses are supposed to focus light to a point on your retina. If they don't, vision is blurry. If you have this problem, you get glasses. Glasses correct the lenses so light focuses to a proper point. So glasses bring both vision and the danger of looking into a bright light up to the level experienced by a person with good vision.

---

There isn't much danger from ordinary lights like incandescent bulbs. Use common sense. And if it isn't comfortable, don't do it.

Ultraviolet lights are a problem. The light is energetic enough to do damage even when not focused. Sunlight contains enough ultraviolet to damage your eyes and skin slowly over the years. That is why doctors harp on sunglasses and sunscreen.

50 years ago, it was common for older people to go blind. Today not so much. In part, people wear sunglasses. In part, lenses in your eyes now can be replaced.

Comment: Thanks great explanation! Regarding the second part of the answer, I meant to ask about normal usage and not about direct staring at the light source. I've edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: The thing is that normal usage (looking at an object) is the same as looking at a light source. We can't see in the dark. We have to shine a light on what we see. We then see light reflected off the object. Each point of the object gives off (reflected) light, which is focused to a point on our retina. This is just the same as a point on the sun or light bulb, except that these make their own light.

Answer (score 3):

Not normal glasses, no.  All a normal pair of glasses do is to let the eye's lens do what it wants to do anyway: form a focussed image on your retina.  So glasses will only cause damage in the case where someone whose sight did not need correction would suffer damage anyway, and even then they will reduce the problem since they are not completely transparent.

And yes, staring at the sun can cause damage.  Staring at bright artificial sources could as well, I suppose.  This happens for people who don't wear glasses just as much as it does for those who do.